# Reloading class/module at runtime in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, classloader

I have an existing MVC web application.

**Part 1**: Is it possible to reload a bean with some changes to the source code ***with out*** *refreshing the application context*?
or,
If I load a class using my custom class loader, will that be managed by spring container? Or can I do anything that it could be managed by Spring container?

**Part 2**: Is it possible to copy field values from old bean to new bean during class reloading?

Comment: Are you talking about during development? Are you running with Spring Boot or an external container? Would JRebel or Spring Loaded be an option?

Comment: @chrylis, it is a web application deployed on Tomcat. I'm asking about redeploying an individual or group of classes when the web application is running.

Comment: Any pointers on this?